# Supermicro server - Replacing faulty disks in a Raid-50

Tags: hard-drive, supermicro

I have a Supermicro server model: X9DR3-F. The server acts as a ESXi host with a Windows 2012R2 server on top of it all.

The server has 22 disks in a RAID-50, with disk 22 being the hot spare.

I have two faulty disks in the RAID and I need to replace them.

**I would really appreciate some help with how to do this. Can I just remove the faulty disks and install two new ones and would the RAID rebuild itself? Or do you have to do it some other way?**

I have tried to install Intel Rapid Storage (RST) utility but I can't find a version that can be installed on the windows server, could it be that it's not recognized as a Supermicro since it's a virtual machine?

I have searched for days for answers but can't find any.

Comment: Yes, you need to have management tools *on the host*. Search for utilities for ESXi. Or reboot and use BIOS-launched utility. Also, some "Intel's RST" happened to be rebranded LSI MegaRAID SAS, so utilities from LSI/Avago/Broadcom might work, it's certainly worth trying.